# Salesforce REST API continuous authentication

Tags: rest, oauth2

Is there a simpler way of accessing my companies data through the REST API, and have the web server that fetches that data be indefinitely authenticated?

I tried using the web server flow with a refresh token but after a while when the sessions expires, the webserver fails to fetch data as its being redirected to the salesforce login page.

The current setup using the login + password flow works as it has the credentials to login, however i am looking for a safer option without exposing our credentials.

My company uses Salesforce to store customer accounts, and orders, which are later displayed on our Wordpress website. When the user logs in on Wordpress their email is used as a key to query Salesforce for their orders.
Steps are:

1. User logs in on wordpress at `www.company.com`
2. `www.company.com` queries `api.company.com` with the users email and
   checks if they have made any orders.
3. If the token is valid
   get data, if expired refresh it with a refresh token.

The problem mentioned is when the session expires and api.company.com is asked to log back into salesforce.

Comment: What is the profile being used for Oauth increase the session time for that profile if company security permits

Comment: Is there a way of setting the session time to indefinite? I saw there is an option under session settings whether to log out the user after a token expiry which i have unchecked but it still logs out.

Comment: For server to server, you need to use the Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow

Comment: You may want to look into setting up a connected app and using the web server flow with refresh token. Also you need to be requesting offline access during the auth to get a proper refresh token,

Comment: @KaonZ That is what im realising. I will need to look into storing the credentials safely.

Comment: @Eric This is what i am doing, but as the problem is outlined, as the token expires, and the session finished, the server is redirected to a login page which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: @ZoranIlievski - there you are not doing something right as the refresh flow is used in all sorts of applications without issue. Its exactly what applications do to keep continuous access until the user revokes the token.

Comment: @Eric So my flow in psuedo code is:  
`Login with organisations credentials - Generates an auth code`  
`Use auth code to get initial access_token and refresh_token and store them`  
`Query Salesforce`  
`if the access_token is valid, manipulate data`  
`if the access_token is invalid, generate a new one with the refresh token`
Still after a while the server cannot fetch data and when you hit an endpoint the refresh token doesnt work and i am asked to sign in again.